# Function using turtle graphics causing errors

Tags: python, function, error-handling, turtle-graphics

I was supposed to create a python code to take items in a list and turn them into a bar graph. In my code, I have a create graph method that works in the first time I run my code, but then when I opt to enter a different data set in, it causes errors, specifically when creategraph is called in a while loop.

```
def creategraph():
bar = turtle.Turtle()
bar.speed(100)
bar.color("black")
bar.fillcolor("green")
bar.pensize(3)
bar.setposition(-200, 0)

xs = [top(text), eighties(text), seventies(text), sixties(text), belowsixties(text)]
#creates list withthe heights ^^

for i in xs:
    draw_bar(bar, i)
bar.penup()
bar.setposition(-200, -50)
bar.forward(40)
bar.write(str("90s"))
bar.forward(40)
bar.forward(40)
bar.write(str("80s"))
bar.forward(40)
bar.forward(40)
bar.write(str("70s"))
bar.forward(40)
bar.forward(40)
bar.write(str("60s"))
bar.forward(40)
bar.forward(40)
bar.write(str("<60"))
bar.forward(40)

bar.hideturtle()

turtle.done()
```

this causes me to get error messages like this:

```
exception was: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\OneDrive\Desktop\CS\Python\__Project2_ScoreAnalysis_Bwoo.py", line 160, in <module>
    creategraph()
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\OneDrive\Desktop\CS\Python\__Project2_ScoreAnalysis_Bwoo.py", line 102, in creategraph
    bar = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\turtle.py", line 3816, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\bwoo2\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

and my loop that calls the graph is

```
codebreaker = 0
```

while codebreaker == 0:
    breaker = False

```
text = input("Please enter the file name: ")
f = open(text)

lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

f.close()

text = lineList

print("Results for", text[0])
print("Number of scores:", findscores(text))
print("High score:", findmax(text))
print("Low score:", findmin(text))
print("Avg:", findavg(text))
print("Check other screen for graph of data")
print("Make sure to close out of graph before processing another file")
creategraph()
print("")
y_n = input("Process another file? y/n :")


if y_n == "y":
    breaker = False
elif y_n == "n":
    breaker = True

if breaker == True:
    codebreaker = 1
```

Any idea what's wrong with the creategraph function?

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that the `turtle.done()` function is only meant to be called *once*, when you are turning control over to the event handler and all future interaction with the code will be through events (mouse clicks, key presses, etc.)  If you are calling `creategraph()` multiple times, then `turtle.done()` has no business being called from it.

Your secondary problem is that you are trying to combine console input with turtle events.  You really should be using turtle's event model only.  That is, instead of `input()` you should be using turtle's `textinput()` method to pop up a dialog based on an event (i.e. pushing a 'new data' pseudo button).